# What changes at 20k rep?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Do you get fireworks and bells at 20,000 or has somebody installed a handful of Claymores?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, your question had many different questions embedded in it, some specifically were more chatty, I tried to edit it down to a specific question and answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You earn [these trusted privileges](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user):

Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:

- Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
- Voting to delete questions immediately after they are closed (even if they are new)
- Editing all tag wikis on the site

Comment: The medium was the message :-). Editing it destroyed it, BUT, destruction was expected. Where is the "Give Kevin a more user friendly message" button? Where is the "Unclose questions immediately after being closed no matter how many Turkey's votedto close them" button ? :-) [[ Gobble gobble gobble ...]]((That's me being a Turkey if that doesn't translate into Euro speak :-).)) 80 to go. Today, probably. Claymores ready ... .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, kevin is much better spoken then myself, I sometimes come off brash meaning a different tone. We close questions for a reason, they have always been reopened when the user has corrected insufficient data or if we were mistaken and poor wordding hid something on topic.

Comment: @Kortuk - I can't quite believe this got closed/edited, the question was as clear as day :-) Surely a *little* humour is okay? I'm pretty sure no-one was going to explain in great detail why you can't swap rep for airmiles.. ;-)

Comment: @OliGlaser, how is it closed? It was edited because a 20k user can look up his rep and asking things like overriding leon is not productive either. Everyone gets a right to vote to reopen long before 20k rep. Asking for armies and such is a joke, but being meta does not make it the place for chatty discussions, they actually made chat for that.

Comment: @Kortuk: Yeah, but chat never works right and has a crappy interface anyway.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I am sorry it does not work for you. I have read many of your posts and would enjoy discussing things in a chat setting where feedback comes faster then 20 minute post notices. I cant think of anyone on the site I would not enjoy talking to. Hopefully they get it working better.

Comment: @Kortuk: Chat has two basic problems.  First it just plain doesn't work on one of the two systems I am frequently on.  Second, there are no discussion threads as best I can tell.  I understand the main site is designed for Q+A, but it would be nice to have a real forum with threads instead of the useless (to me anyway) chat.  Even if it worked as intended, it's not what I want.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, yeah, it does not have threads, it is meant to be a simple messaging system.

Comment: @OlinLathrop anyone can create a new chat room, this is essentially a discussion thread, in fact this is what is done when a string of comments gets too long and gets moved to a chat room. If you can't get it to work on a computer then report the bug. If you think it is a crappy interface then recommend an improvement.